# Successful deliveries 178%. Why?

Tags: civimail

Sometimes I have more than 100% successful deliveries in the mailings. For a 2700 intended recipients I can have 4800 successful deliveries. I wonder why this happens!

This group contains around 2700 "individual" and 2500 "organizations".

Any help? Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you give more information about what version of CiviCRM you are using, which screen / report give you this % ? Why do you expect 2700 recipients if you have 5200 contacts in this group ?

Comment: Also, what method of mailing are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like we have an overachiever here!

More seriously, I suspect that you may have found a bug in the count of recipients that occurs when you have the mailing set to email each contact, regardless of whether the email address duplicates another recipient of the mailing.

It wouldn't be surprising if practically all of the organizations had email addresses that were each actually the same as an individual's email address.  If you throw them all into one mailing (by your account and samuelsov's math), you'd have 5200 contacts.  Remove a few because they have no email, a few where the email is on hold, a few that have do not email, and a few that bounce, and voila--that's 4800 successful deliveries.

If that's the case, I suspect that the handy counter in CiviMail is simply assuming that you're using the CiviMail setting that suppresses repeat mailings to the same address per run.

You can confirm all this by clicking on the details in your mailing report and viewing the list of actual successful deliveries.  I suspect that you'll see both contacts and their organizations, many of whom have the same email addresses.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Actually the mailing is sent to all the email addresses of any contact (we made a module that does that automatically), maybe the counter counts every email it sends to, instead contacts only. So if a contact has 3 emails, then it might count as 3 instead 1. In the report there are lots of duplicate contacts (the same email address sent twice, even three times). There are organizations as well. Some organizations have the same email address than a contact...

Comment: You found the issue, then. Your custom module changes the number of recipients without changing the posted number, which is calculated independently. In the future, you'll get better answers by providing more information in the question, especially if there are customizations that directly affect the feature you're asking about. There's no way anyone could've anticipated that you had this kind of customization.